# assign 2 values to an array item

Tags: php, arrays

I have this PHP Array:

```
$statuses = array('Customer Reply', 'Needs Action', 'Open');
```

I then run this code:

```
foreach($statuses as $status) {
    echo '<tr>
    <td colspan="8" bgcolor="#F36F25"><strong><font color="#FFFFFF">'.$status.' ('.count($records).')</font></strong></td>
    </tr>';
}
```

But i want to be able to assign a different colour (for the background) for each `$statuses`

Comment: Ok, what's your question?

Comment: @Hamish i want to be able to assign a different background colour for the table for each of the $statuses

Comment: Change the value of #F36F25, or replace it with a variable.

Comment: thats what I'm asking, how can i assign a variable to each item in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$statuses = array('Customer Reply' => '#FFF', 'Needs Action' => '#000', 'Open' => '#F36F25');

foreach($statuses as $status => $color) { ?>
<tr>
  <td colspan ="8" bgcolor="<?php echo $color; ?>"><font color="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $status; echo count($records); ?></font></strong></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is what you want..

```
But i want to be able to assign a different colour (for the background) for each
```

.

```
$statuses = array('color_code'=>'Customer Reply', 'color_code'=>'Needs Action', 'color_code'=>'Open');
foreach($statuses as $color=>$status) {
    echo '<tr>
    <td colspan="8" bgcolor="'. $color .'"><strong><font color="#FFFFFF">'.$status.'</font></strong></td>
    </tr>\n';
}
```

Comment: Why are you basically copying my answer?

Comment: @Daan, Is it really? How can you say?

Comment: Because of the associative array obviously.

Comment: @Daan you are making me laugh my friend, my example is different then you used. If you write code before me then you think i copied you? hows? I had multiple tabs opened. And i skipped this tabs, but filled the answer without any activity and then leave from here. IS IT MEAN I COPIED YOU? HOWZ SILLY IT IS..

Answer (score -1):

Depends on your need. Modulo is what you wants.

```
$statuses = array('Customer Reply', 'Needs Action', 'Open');

foreach($statuses as $key => $status) {
  $color = 'white';
  if($key%2) {
    $color = 'black';
  }
    echo '<tr>
    <td colspan="8" bgcolor="'. $color .'"><strong><font color="#FFFFFF">'.$status.'</font></strong></td>
    </tr>\n';
}
```